# P5JS CORS error after making it a node app

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

So I have a P5JS app which has a very simple preload function:

```
function preload() {
  json = loadJSON(getCurrentViewersUrl());
}
```

which calls this function and returns the request url:

```
function getCurrentViewersUrl() {
  return "https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/" + STREAM_NAME + "/chatters";
```

}

This all worked swimingly when using `http-server` to start my P5JS app.

I've now just switched so that my P5JS code is served up by my node app.

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(9999);

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

But now, with making this change I'm now getting the cors policy error:

> Access to fetch at
>
> ```
> 'https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/x/chatters' from origin 'http://localhost:9999' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> ```
>
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

My question is, why am I getting this now and not before?

This is what the request looks like:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you examine the request sent by the before and after code? My guess is that one is setting `no-cors` and one isn't?

Comment: How can I explicity set no-cors in p5js? @KevinWorkman

Comment: I've added the network in an edit @KevinWorkman

Comment: Have you tried [express' CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) ?

Comment: I just tried it @GeorgeProfenza still get the same error

Comment: Since the request is going to a third-party site, Express' CORS settings seem unrelated to the problem. Try making the request with https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere and see if that works. You don't want to make the request wth `no-cors` because you can't use an opaque response (no JSON payload).